# TortoiseSVN incorrectly reports all revisions as merged

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repository with the standard trunk/branches/tags layout where HEAD is r383, all development takes place in trunk and changes up to r367 have already been published in Production site.

Customer has decided that we wants some pending changes in Production but not all. So I decided to create a new branch that would reflect code that's ready to release, starting from the trunk revision that's currently published:

[image: Branch/tag]

Now I want to merge some revisions from trunk into my new branch. To my surprise, Tortoise SVN reports the complete trunk as already ported:

[image: Merge - Show log]

The funny thing is that I can still cherry-pick the revisions I want, the merge completes successfully (I don't even need to select "Force the merge") and `svn:mergeinfo` gets properly populated:

[image: Edit properties]

... but I cannot use TortoiseSVN to visually identify what's ported and what not.

Have I done something fundamentally wrong or I've just hit a bug?

Comment: TortoiseSVN is 1.9.x, right? `svn:merge` means `svn:mergeinfo`, right?

Comment: @bahrep Yes, more exactly a dev build (TortoiseSVN 1.9.99, Build 27362 - 64 Bit -dev) under Subversion 1.9.5. I'm fixing the property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in TortoiseSVN. As of today, it's already fixed in [nightly builds](https://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/1.9.x/).